# Как реализовать безопасный вектор?

Tags: c++

Есть вот такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>
class Array
{

T* arr;
int capacity;
int current;

public:

Array()
{
  arr = new T[1];
  capacity = 1;
  current = 0;
}

void push(T data)
    {
        if (current == capacity) {
            T* temp = new T[2 * capacity];
            for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
                temp[i] = arr[i];
            }
            delete[] arr;
            capacity *= 2;
            arr = temp;
    }
        arr[current] = data;
        current++;
    }
    
void push(int data, int index)
    {
            arr[index] = data;
    }
  
void pop() 
  {
     current--; 
  }
  
int size() 
  {
     return current; 
  }
  
int getcapacity() 
  {
     return capacity; 
  }

void print ()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < current; i++)
  cout << arr[i] << " ";
  cout << "\n";
}

~Array()
{
  delete[] arr;
}

friend Array& operator + (Array &p,int z)
{
  p.arr[p.current] = z;
  p.current++;
  return p;
}

Array& operator += (Array &d2)
{
  int cap = this -> current < d2.current ? this -> current : d2.current;
    for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++)
        this -> arr[i] += d2.arr[i];
    return *this;
}

Array& operator = (const Array &d)
{
  current = d.current;
    for (int i = 0; i < current; i++)
        arr[i] = d.arr[i];
    return *this;
}

T& operator[] (int index)  
{     
  return arr[index]; 
}

Array& operator--()
{
    --current;
      return *this;
}

Array& operator--(int)
{
    current--;
    return *this; 
}

friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, const Array &a)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < a.current; i++) {
      out << a.arr[i] << ' ';
  }
  out  << "\n";
  return out;
}

friend bool operator > (const Array &d1, const Array &d2)
{
    return d1.current > d2.current;
}
 
friend bool operator >= (const Array &d1, const Array &d2)
{
    return d1.current >= d2.current;
}
 
friend bool operator < (const Array &d1, const Array &d2)
{
    return d1.current < d2.current;
}
 
friend bool operator <= (const Array &d1, const Array &d2)
{
    return d1.current <= d2.current;
}

friend bool operator == (const Array &d1, const Array &d2)
{
    return d1.current == d2.current;
}

friend bool operator != (const Array &d1, const Array &d2)
{
    return d1.current != d2.current;
}
};
template<class T>
class SafeArray: public Array<int>
{
  T* arr;
  public:
  int capacity;
  int current;
  int up_ind;
  int low_ind;
 SafeArray(int upper_ind, int lower_ind)
 {
  arr = new T[upper_ind];
  capacity = upper_ind;
  current = lower_ind;
  up_ind = upper_ind;
  low_ind = lower_ind;
 }

};
int main() 
{
 SafeArray<int> a(3 , 6);
return 0;
}
```

Остановился на этом, дальше не понимаю как мне реализовать сам этот безопасный вектор. Он должен определяться верхними и нижними пределами, и помогите с вводом и выводом из потока, пожалуйста, тоже не особо понимаю, как это реализовать
Надеюсь наследовал правильно класс

Еще есть вопрос по поводу оператора присваивания, который должен по идее быть реализован через функции базового класса

Comment: видимо как минимум нужно проверять индекс здесь `void push(int data, int index)` (похоже либо имя неудачное, либо оно сломано)

Comment: можете написать,пожалуйста? мне так легче будет понять

Comment: нет, потому что не понятно, что именно должна делать эта функция

Comment: какая именно? void push(int data, int index) делает замену элемента массива,где data - новый элемент, а index - позиция заменяемого элемента, но почему мы говорим об этой функции? она же относится к классу простого вектора, а мне нужно реализовать безопасный сейчас

Comment: push - это добавить. А у Вас void push(int data, int index) модифицирует элемент. Она больше похожа на `operator[]`

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум я бы переписал несколько функций

```
void push(int data, int index)
{
        arr[index] = data;
}
```

у нее плохое имя. Может update? и индекс второй параметр? ну ок. Но почему она принимает дату как int?

```
void update(const T& data, int index)
{
  if (index < 0 || index >= current) {
    throw "ой, индекс вне разумных пределов";
  }
  arr[index] = data;
}
```

а может лучше где то так?

```
T& operator[]( int index)
{
   return arr[index];
}


T& at( int index)
{
   if (index < 0 || index >= current) {
    throw "ой, индекс вне разумных пределов";
  }
   return arr[index];
}
```

(да, так принято, что первая не проверяет индекс, а вторая - должна)

И теперь можно будет писать arr[1] = 4; и это будет работать. Красиво же?

теперь следующая

```
void pop() 
{
   current--; 
}
```

а если вызвать функцию много много раз?

```
void pop() 
{
   if (current <= 0) {
      throw "хватит, нет больше элементов";
   }
   current--; 
}
```

safe array? так это просто ограниченный по индексам массив? тогда возьмите функции выше и просто правильно проставьте там лимиты. И всех делов то. Правда pop для такого массива будет странным. Очень странным.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, да, действительно, некоторые моменты странные)) Но я учусь, поэтому) Сейчас все понял

А если создать новый класс - SafeArray, который принимает 2 значения (нижний предел, верхний предел) - как его написать вообще? Я попытался здесь
```
class SafeArray: public Array<int>
{
  T* arr;
  public:
  int capacity;
  int current;
  int up_ind;
  int low_ind;
 SafeArray(int upper_ind, int lower_ind)
 {
  arr = new T[upper_ind];
  capacity = upper_ind;
  current = lower_ind;
  up_ind = upper_ind;
  low_ind = lower_ind;
 }
```

Comment: Он не выводится почему-то(да,я его не заполнил, но вывестись-то должен)

Comment: Под реализацией ввода и вывода из потока, насколько я понимаю, нужно использовать cin и cout, это перегрузка оператора, там и ostream и friend нужно использовать, но голова не соображает как это сделать

Comment: Для начала попробуйте написать то, как должно выглядеть использование Вашего класса, такие себе юнит тесты (TDD), тогда будет легче